# How to assingn my code properly to a button?

Tags: excel, vba

This code works perfectly it saves an excel file to CSV-UTF8 and adds a timestamp in front of the file named "Test".

However, when I assign this code to a button, I'm always getting an error 400 for some reason.

So what I did is put the same code inside a module and debug it, and it didn't give me any errors it executed the code without any problems.

Can someone help me get this to work while using a button?

```
Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()
 Dim wbNew As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim name As String, myPath As String

comp = Environ("username")
myPath = "C:\" & comp & "\Testing\"  'use here the path you need
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
name = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hh.mm") & " Testing"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8  'new way
wbNew.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

[Error 1004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGnCk.png)

Recieving the following error on this part:

```
wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8  'new way
```

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what the code is supposed to do? Is there one workbook or are there more? You haven't opened any, and you haven't copied any worksheets.

Comment: This code is supposed to save the active worksheet as CSV UTF-8 in the myPath.

Comment: What is the point of the variables `wsSource` and `wsTemp` you assign them a couple of times, but don't do anything with them.

Comment: So there are two workbooks: `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` (containing the code) or are they the same?

Comment: Sorry, no it just one workbook with different sheets in it. I'm trying to save the second worksheet as CSV UTF-8.

Comment: I have updated above code, when debugging I'm getting this 1004 error on line: wbNew.SaveAs myPath & "\" & name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8  'new way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export to CSV

- 'Semicolon users' might want to add `, Local:=True` to the `SaveAs` line to get the result separated by the semicolon.
- `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath` will open the folder in `Windows File Explorer`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveWorkSheetAsCSV()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Testing"
    ' or:
    'FolderPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Testing"
    ' Print the path to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
    'Debug.Print FolderPath
    
    Dim FileName As String: FileName = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hh.mm ") & " Test"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8 ', Local:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink FolderPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this still seems to crash on the same line.

Comment: What are the error number and the description? Try using the line `Debug.Print FolderPath` right after `FolderPath = ...`, to see if it is the right path: it has to exist (it will not be created).

Comment: I think you forgot `\Users`. I've corrected it. Try now.

Comment: Getting a runtime error 1004 with dwb.SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & FileName & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8

Comment: Omg I had put the Users in but forgot \ at the end. Let me try again!

Comment: Note, that you can test the path with Dir: `If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: This is great man it works but I can't get it to work with semicolon I have added , Local:=True after the SaveAs.

Comment: You have to add it at the end. See my correction. Just remove the comment character `'`. BTW, I meant this only if your system list separator is a semicolon, if you in the cells use e.g. `=If(A1=0;"";B1)`.

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008, it works really good but I see a lot of semicolons on places where there is no data, should that matter?